# Editing a htaccess file to redirect site except for contents of one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

hi so i want one site to 301 to another except for one directory and its contents
so if i put `http://www.oldsite.com/whaterver` I go to `http://www.newsite.co.uk`
so far I have

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.co.uk
```

this redirect the whole site with no problems I added this above the first line

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/blog/
```

I think Im mixing to different modules together here..any help would be great thanks
dave

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newsite.co.uk [L,R=301,NC]
```